# How to keep a website or PHP-script loading indefinitely?

Tags: php

This is supposed to be part of a protection against hacking-attempts. The idea is to keep the hacker/attacker waiting for a long time, after a hacking-attempt is detected.

The detection of such attempts is not part of my question.
I only need to know if/how it is possible to create a PHP-script that will simply keep loading, as if the website/server is exceptionally slow, preferably without creating a high server-load by the connection being kept open.

I thought there must be some way to simply stop the PHP script on the server without notifying the user/client that there won't be a response from the server. Or maybe something similar?

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible. The connection will have to remain open, otherwise the client knows that the server is done (when the connection terminates). You could just set your PHP max exec time to some high value and do something like this `while (true) { sleep(10); }` which won't consume cycles.

Comment: PHP has a maximum execution time of 30s (which you can customize) but I would not recommand this. You better be returning a Bad Request response with no content. And keep returning this for every request made by the attacker.

Comment: No attacker is that stupid, sorry. Attacking scripts use a timeout to not waste their time.

Comment: This is a horrible idea. You're just going to make it extremely easy to DoS your site. If you've already written code to "detect the hack" then just block the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [sleep()](http://php.net/sleep), but there’s a huge downside:

While `sleep()` doesn’t use any CPU time, the connection has to be kept open for a long time (which means you could reach the connection limit on your server) and a PHP process would be running uselessly (which consumes quite a bit of memory and might also make you hit a process limit).

So that means that someone you have considered to be an attacker would actually have *more* leverage to run a Denial of Service attack against your website.

I don’t think there’s a resource-friendly way of doing this with PHP alone.

Comment: What you point out has nothing to do with php. It is a general truth.

Comment: But it’s an even bigger problem with PHP due to the way web servers are set up and the memory consumption per process.

Comment: Sorry, but why should that be the case? What is special about the "web server setup" and "their memory consumption"? A web server is a simple process like any other. PHP is a simple scripting language like any other. There is nothing special here.

Comment: Because PHP can only handle one request at a time. So for each process you want to run concurrently, you need another process that consumes memory. This, as you point out, is true for many technologies, but there are some that don’t have this problem.

Comment: And where exactly is that different to any other environment? Besides the fact that it is not really true? Certainly there are solutions like threads or asynchronous approaches, but that only shifts the facts, it does not solve them. The bottleneck is not the language of the environment, but the platform underneath, the von-Neumann architecture.

Comment: For example, node.js can handle many requests at the same time with just one process. But yes, any CGI-integrated language like PHP has the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, but that is nonsense. You can do the same with php if you want to. But that does not solve the issue at hand of wasting your servers resources for absolutely nothing. So this leads nowhere. Let's drop this, the OPs approach simply does not make much sense.